# What is the Fourier transform of an exponential function with a delta function as part of its argument?

Tags: fourier-transform, integration, dirac-delta-distributions

Specifically, I'm wondering if it is possible to integrate something like this

$$ x(t) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(f) \ e^{i2\pi f t} \ df $$

where

$$ X(f) = \exp\left\{\frac{\alpha_0}{2}\delta(f-f_0)-i\left[\frac{\alpha_0}{2\pi}\frac{1}{f-f_0}+\frac{\pi}{\kappa}(f-f_0)^2\right]\right\}$$

The need for the integral is arising from trying to model spectral hole burning, with a delta function shaped hole being burned in.

Comment: It's VERY bad object. Already $\delta(x)^2$ is highly problematic and but you are talking about exponent involving arbitrary power

Comment: What you can do is regularize this delta and expect the result to be reg-dependent

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: This expression is meaningless as it is written. However, in real life applications delta function in such expression usually occurs as an approximation. This whole you are working with probably really has some finite width. Hence you can try replacing $\delta$ with some function which is very sharply peaked at zero.

Comment: It's meaningless to talk about $f(\delta(x-x_0))$. In mathematics only theory on $\delta(f(x-x_0))$ has been established.

Comment: @Blazej yeah, but as I mentioned earlier different regularizations may lead to different results. So approximation with delta-function most probably is not possible and you need to know actual shape of the hole.

Answer (score 1):

So it's pretty clear what it presumably *would* mean but I'm not sure that you can really make it work. What it *would* mean would be, you'd expand the expression as a power series. Therefore the result would involve things like:
$$
\int dx~\big[\delta(x)\big]^2 f(x).$$You can say a couple things about this. For example, by the rules of Dirac $\delta$-functions, morally this should be $\delta(0)~f(0)$ and therefore should be $\delta(0) = \infty$ unless,say, $f(0) = 0$ or so. If you run it with some actual examples you should find a similar divergence; for example with Gaussians you can work out that:$$\begin{array}{rccl}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx & (2\pi s^2)^{-1/2} \exp\left[-\frac12 (x/s)^2\right]&=& 1 \\
\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx & \Big( (2\pi s^2)^{-1/2} \exp\left[-\frac12 (x/s)^2\right]\Big)^2 &=& 1/\sqrt{4\pi s^2}
\end{array}$$The former acts like a $\delta$-function for $s \to 0;$ the latter clearly diverges as $s \to 0$ instead of going to 1.